# Strange behavior from decrypt EVP envelope_open()

Tags: c++, encryption

I have a simple program that encrypts files in a directory. I can iterate through and everything works perfectly. This is using pub/priv key pair. When decrypting one file at a time, it works as it should. However, if there are multiple files in a directory, or even if I put the filenames in a vector and fopen them for reading/writing respectively, it ONLY decrypts the LAST file in the vector/directory. How is this even possible? It fails on everyone of them on OpenFinal(). Here is the function and heart of the program. Everything else is solid. As stated, it works as a standalone program if I just decrypt one file manually or if there is just ONE file in the directory or vector.

Any help would be appreciated. This makes no sense at all. It seems like an implementation issue on their end.

```
void handleErrors(void)
{
    // perror("Error: ");
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
}


int envelope_open(EVP_PKEY *priv_key, unsigned char *ciphertext,
                  int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *encrypted_key,
                  int encrypted_key_len, unsigned char *iv,
                  unsigned char **plaintext, int *plaintext_len)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int len = 0, ret = 0;
    unsigned char *tmpptxt = NULL;

    if((ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()) == NULL)
        return 0;

    if ((tmpptxt = (unsigned char*)malloc(ciphertext_len)) == NULL)
    {
        printf("tmptxt error!\n");
        handleErrors();
    }

    if(EVP_OpenInit(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), encrypted_key, encrypted_key_len,
                    iv, priv_key) != 1)
    {
        printf("OpenInit error\n");
        handleErrors();
    }

    if(EVP_OpenUpdate(ctx, tmpptxt, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len) != 1)
            {
        printf("OpenUpdate error\n");
        handleErrors();
    }
    *plaintext_len = len;

    if(EVP_OpenFinal(ctx, tmpptxt + len, &len) != 1)
            {
        printf("OpenFinal error\n");
                handleErrors();
    }
    *plaintext_len += len;

    *plaintext = tmpptxt;
    tmpptxt = NULL;
    ret = 1;
 err:
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    free(tmpptxt);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: This isn't an "implementation issue on their end"; it's *your* issue on *your* end. Ex: `*plaintext = tmpptxt;` stores the output buffer pointer, but you then fall past the `err:` label into `free(tmpptxt);` which dangles that pointer. The code back in `main` dereferencing that address, therefore, invokes *undefined behavior*. I have a lot more comments, but without a proper [mcve] it's near-impossible to guarantee their validity. Best of luck.

Comment: no, sorry that has nothing to do with it. Nothing calls err so it is never invoked. it was a label i was using before I started using handleErrors. I just forgot to remove that but i just removed that label now and of course it is still producing the same behavior.

Comment: The label had nothing to do with it, but you're right about the miss-pick regardless,  the setting of `tmpptxt = NULL;` is what prevents the dangle (since you're just `free`'ing a `NULL` afterward which is perfectly fine, so my bad on that, admittedly). Wish I could run your code, but can't, as it isn't a proper [mcve]. A debugger is really your only option at this point.

Comment: the rest of the code just sets up the keys, writes them to a file, reads them in to pass off to envelope_open(). it also reads in the encrypted_key and iv from text files created from the encrypt program so to keep things simple, i didn't post it and i dont think it is necessary but i know people might want to hang me for that. i can tell you that when there is only one file in the directory, it works, but more than one file, it only decrypts the last one. my iterator has nothing to do with it either because i am even using a vector this time which has all the files as the full path.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the 'vector', and the iterator `t`, which makes code like `const char *filename = t[i].c_str();` (or anything using `t[i]`) bogus regardless, since `std::vector<T>::iterator` doesn't provide an overload of `operator[]`. People will want [mcve] s because they no longer have to guess whether the code posted is the code failing, nor do they have to guess what lays within the confines of mystery for the things you didn't provide. They won't 'hang' you for it; but they will be much more likely to not bother *trying* to answer the post.

Comment: i may post the entire code but the user will need to generate a new set of pub/priv keys and include the private portion of bob in this one. they will also need the encrypt program as well. however, i guarantee you my `t[i]` absolutely does work, i am able  to iterate through the entire vector and operate on each iteration. but also that does not matter because i've also written it without any vector, by using my Recursive function on the fly and it still fails

Comment: here is the error i am receiving: `88140000:error:1C800064:Provider routines:ossl_cipher_unpadblock:bad decrypt:providers\implementations\ciphers\ciphercommon_block.c:124:` based on this site https://gitlab.symas.net/symas-public/openssl/-/blob/1ed3249f253e4490a813279e2eb253c8e5cfaabb/providers/implementations/ciphers/ciphercommon_block.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was overwriting the key and iv returned from `envelope_seal()`. I looked over the fact it was unique. Each file must have this key and iv along with the private key and passphrase on the key to be able to decrypt a file. So this is definitely secure ... until someone cracks `AES 256` of course.